# Can I use DCT and LSB method for multiple watermarking?

Tags: steganography

I have an idea of applying DCT on an image and then embed text into the LSB of the coefficient of DCT and transmit the image to B (the receiver). Now, using the same procedure, can B transmit another watermark along with the previous one with this method to another person? Is this a suitable procedure?

Comment: I'd say no, unless A and B had some rules so they wouldn't write over each others information. maybe they would agree that odd bits would be used by A and even bits by B. But this halves your secret bit rate, and the bit rate of a hidden message using the LSB of a DCT is pretty small already I'm guessing.

Comment: @daniel There are algorithms that can provide error correction and detection with arbitrary precision (e.g. reed-solomon codes), which could provide resilience against a given number of bits being corrupted by another party.

Comment: @Sana Is this suitable for _what_? Yes, it would work in that you could embed information in a (lossless) image, but what is the purpose? No one can answer you as to whether or not it is a suitable procedure if no one knows what it is necessary for.

Comment: @forest what do you mean? What happens if you have 1 message of 100 bits, and a nose source of any given number (up to 100 bits) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_capacity

Comment: @daniel Obviously error correction codes expand the amount of data required to hold a given message. The method of transmission is irrelevant. All that matters is that an (ECC-protected) message of a given length is able to withstand the corruption of an arbitrary number of bits (no bits are more important than any others).

Comment: @forest but for here you can't assume you can increase the amount of data you are sending, you might only get one jpeg file of a regular size, maybe you can use 5% of that for a secret message without it becoming obviously tampered with. Some safe guesses are the data is already compressed and encrypted and the error correction done outside on the image, adding this A then B situation means moving the error correction inside, a trade off is you can't be sure you get the message (as the noise amount increases)

Comment: @daniel Yeah that's true. I am assuming the data can fit in an image (wouldn't work for JPEG though since it mangles the LSB. Maybe for lossless JPEG2000).

Answer (score 1):

Since you usually compress images, which would do something very similar, at least in the case of jpeg compression, but would completely omit or severely reduce LSBs, I guess, no, in practice not.

If you're sending around full-color pictures uncompressed, at least I'd look at the entropy of your LSBs and the PSD, and the latter would probably lead to the suspicion that you're using steganography.